# using sed command grab lines between n blocks

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I have n blocks like `critical---end1` and `warning end2` like below:

```
zczdczdczd
zdfzdfdf
zdfzdfzd
zdfzdf
zdfzdf


critical
abc
def
ghi
end1

zdfzd
zdfzddf

warning
abs
def
ghi
end2

zdfzdfzd
zdfzdfz
zdfdfz

critical
abc
def
ghi
end1

zdfzdfzdf
zdfzddzf

critical
asdasd
asdasd
asdasd
end1

asda
asdasd
asdasd

warning
asdas
asdasd
asdasd
end2

asdas
asdasd

warning
asdasd
asdasda
asdas
end1
```

I have to grep only all the blocks `critical---end1` and `warning-----end2` using `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [grab lines between two words using sed command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452308/grab-lines-between-two-words-using-sed-command)

Comment: deleted that i didnot know how to align.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you try to indicate a desired output as well as what you tried? Note you can format your text with the `{}` button in the edit bar.

Comment: thank you sir. pls help me about my requirements

Answer (score 0):

Some like this:

```
awk -v RS= '(/critical/ && /end1/) || (/warning/ && /end2/)' file
critical
abc
def
ghi
end1
warning
abs
def
ghi
end2
critical
abc
def
ghi
end1
critical
asdasd
asdasd
asdasd
end1
warning
asdas
asdasd
asdasd
end2
```

---

Here is another `awk`.  This version does not care if data is in block or not, and it preserve spacing.

```
awk '/critical/ {f="c";next} /warning/ {f="w";next} (/end1/&&f=="c")||(/end2/&&f=="w") {print d;d=f=""} f {d=$0?d"\n"$0:$0}' t

abc
def
ghi

abs
def
ghi

abc
def
ghi

asdasd
asdasd
asdasd

asdas
asdasd
asdasd
```

---

To get data to separate files:

```
awk '/critical/ {f="c";next} /warning/ {f="w";next} /end1/&&f=="c" {print d > "critical";d=f=""} /end2/&&f=="w" {print d > "warning";d=f=""} f {d=$0?d"\n"$0:$0}' file
```

This saves data to two files `critial` and  `warning`

Comment: thank you both are working. pls explaing how it works.

Comment: Setting RS to nothing  `-v RS=` makes `awk` works on blocks (space separated) instead of lines.  Then it test if the block contains both the word `critical` and `end1` or it contains `warning` and `end2`.  It will not be printed if it contaisn `warning` and `end1` like the last section.

Comment: i dont want to display block names like critical and end1 just i need to display the contents inside that blocks

Comment: @user3428462  I have updated second solution in my post to not display block name and end section.

Comment: i want to redirect critical-- end1 block to one file and warning--end2 block to another file. how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/^critical$/,/^end1$/p; /^warning$/,/^end2$/p' file |
grep -v -e '^critical$' -e '^warning$' -e '^end[12]$'
```

The `-n` tells `sed` not to print all lines by default, and the other two commands are ranges that print all lines between the first and second address using the `p` command.

ETA: to miss out the delimiting lines, the easiest way is to get rid of them with `grep -v`, which prints only lines that don't match any of the patterns given.

Comment: If there is a section starting with `critical` and ending with `end2` this will print it.

Comment: And it prints section starting with `warning` and ends with `end1`, last section in example.

Comment: Hi i dont want to display critical and end1 i nedd inside what in that block only.

Comment: i want to redirect critical-- end1 block to one file and warning--end2 block to another file. how to do this –